# Can I use wildcards in "IN" MySQL statement?

Tags: sql, mysql, wildcard

I would like to run something like:

```
select * from table where field in ("%apple%", "%orange%")
```

Is there a way? Or at least is there a better way than dynamically building query for every keyword:

```
select * from table where field like "%apple%" or field like "%orange%"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm not sure it's any better than what you came up with but you could use [MySQL's regex capabilities](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html):

```
select * from my_table where field rlike 'apple|orange';
```

Also, as others have mentioned, you could use [MySQL's full text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) capabilities (but only if you're using the MyISAM engine).

Comment: Yeah, looks like the easiest approach. Thanks. Hopefully it doesn't affect performance much.

Comment: @serg555: I don't think you'll get good performance out of the regex approach because no index will be used. I would recommend the full text search approach.

Comment: Yeah, but it also has its disadvantages: only myisam tables, only one end wildcards.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a better solution would be to use a [boolean search against a fulltext index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html)?

EDIT: I looked it up and it only supports wildcards at the *end* of words:

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD FULLTEXT INDEX (field);

SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH (field)
AGAINST ('orange* apple*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably should look at [MySQL's full text indexing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.4/en/fulltext-search.html), if that is what you're trying to do.

Answer (score -2):

In Oracle, you can do:

```
select * from table where
regexp_like (column, 'apple|orange', 'i')
```

You can use more complex regexp.  The 'i' makes it insensitive.
See [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm#SQLRF00501)