# Mysql query with In clause regex

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have a SQL query like this:

```
"select f.filterid as filtename, f.id as filtertext " +
    "from filter f " + 
    "where group_Id = '" + id +"' " + 
    "OR groupIds like '%." + id + ".%' ";
```

And I want to pass a list of ids to this query to make performance better. I don't know whether REGEX works with in an `IN` clause. And I tried the below one which is not working and not sure what to use in case of REGEX.

```
"select f.filterid as filtename, f.id as filtertext from filter f " + 
    "where group_Id in ("+StringUtils.join(ids, "','")+")" + 
    "OR groupIds in ("+StringUtils.join(ids, "','")+")"";
```

Thanks.

Comment: group_Id is a  numeric datatype of varchar data type?

Comment: group_Id  is int and groupIds is varchar

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use the `Query#setParameter` to achieve this, if you are using JPA you can easily supply your ids list in the setParameter.

But for your current resolution you may try the below changes.

Not sure if your group_Id column expects integer or string datatype, well I will propose changes for either of the cases.

**If it expects String** - You are missing the starting " ' " change your code as below

**If it expects integer type** - You should not wrap your comma separator with " ' ", remove them as below

```
"select f.filterid as filtename, f.id as filtertext from filter f " + "where group_Id in ("+StringUtils.join(ids, ",")+")" + "OR groupIds in ("+"'"+StringUtils.join(ids, "','")+"'"+")";
```

Trying running this query and see if you get the desired resultset

Comment: I need to pass list of regex string for groupIds which i am not able to do it in plain sql select query.

Comment: How your regex string looks like?

Comment: It looks like 1.12345.2 and i am only interested in like doing with list of %.12345.% values. 
See this post here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540087/can-the-in-operator-use-like-wildcards-in-oracle

Comment: You cannot use LIKE with IN clause in MySQL DB, option for you would be to repeat the LIKE clause for the number of elements in your groupIds list

Comment: if i have a list of one million then the query looks awful.

Comment: You cannot pass more 1000 params in your IN clause, that's a restriction from DB, in such case you better of dividing your list into chunks of 500 or 1000 records list and then iteratively call your select on it

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem lies in the use of method  StringUtils.join.
you can edit your sql like the following code.

```
 select f.filterid as filtename, f.id as filtertext from filter f where group_Id in ('groupA_id', 'groupB_id', 'groupC_id')
```

if your `ids` is `{"groupA_id", "groupB_id", "groupC_id"}`, then

```
"select f.filterid as filtename, f.id as filtertext from filter f where group_Id in (" + "'" + StringUtils.join(ids, "','") + "'" +")"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this:

```
Query query = session.Query("select f.filterid as filtename, f.id as filtertext from filter f where group_Id in :list");
query.SetParameterList(":list", ListOfIds);
```