# SQL In() with Wildcard Operators For MULTIPLE COLUMNS

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, wildcard

I need to search for a text in multiple columns of my table. Right now I have `WHERE 'text' in (col1, col2, col3, col4)`, but I'd need to add Wildcard operators to the text, as it should find any results that contain the text anywhere in any of these columns.
I COULD use `WHERE col1 LIKE '%text%' OR col2 LIKE '%text%' OR col3 LIKE '%text%' OR col4 LIKE '%text'`, but I wanted to know if there's any way to use the Wildcard Operators with `in()` or any other way to do this easier, as using a lot of `OR` can quickly get confusing.

Since Stackoverflow is forcing me to explain how this question is different from [Can I use wildcards in "IN" MySQL statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652318/can-i-use-wildcards-in-in-mysql-statement) :
The linked question only covers multiple SEARCH TEXT OPTIONS, I need multiple COLUMN options. I DO NOT KNOW how to use the answer of the linked question for my case. I tried it and it did not work.

Comment: @diiN__________ No, since that article focuses on multiple search-text options, I need multiple column options. I wouldn't know how to use the answer of that article for my needs. Thank you, though!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20301358/mysql-look-for-the-same-string-in-multiple-columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just concatinate them with a separator.

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table 
WHERE CONCAT_WS('|', col1, col2, col3, col4) LIKE '%text%'
```

In MySql 8 one could also use an `EXISTS` for this

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table t
WHERE EXISTS (
  select 1
  from (
    select t.col1 as col union all
    select t.col2 union all
    select t.col3 union all
    select t.col4
  ) q
  where col LIKE '%text%'
);
```

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=668ecc1cd46826d4782cbb88df3908a3)*